# Umbraco, Controller and Glass Mapper for Macros

Tags: model-view-controller, macros, umbraco, glass-mapper

I cant find that much documentation regarding MVC and Macros in Umbraco.
Does anyone know if its possible to use controllers for the Macros before they are passed down to the view?

Also.. does anyone know if Glass Mapper has support for Macros? Guess I could extend Glass Mapper myself, but would prefer not to if its already built in :).

Comment: This is a Q&A site.  Asking 2 questions at the same time makes it difficult to answer.  Make 2 questions instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use controller for partials and for macro partials, so the answer is yes.
More information can be found in the documentation about "[custom controllers](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/custom-controllers)"